# Elasticsearch-6.6.0 not starting on windows

Tags: java, php, elasticsearch, error-handling, jvm

I am trying to install [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started.html)

In the command prompt,I type in:

```
cd C:\Users\Prime Jay\Downloads\elasticsearch-6.6.0\elasticsearch-6.6.0\bin

set ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms200m -Xmx500m
echo %ES_JAVA_OPTS%
elasticsearch
```

This happens:

```
[2019-02-21T16:55:11,033][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [5ZUrCC7] using [1]
data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [160.6gb], net total_space [270.3g
b], types [NTFS]
[2019-02-21T16:55:11,053][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [5ZUrCC7] heap size
[487.2mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [unknown]
[2019-02-21T16:55:11,063][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [5ZUrCC7] node name
derived from node ID [5ZUrCC7yR_GPEA3ghcw8Vg]; set [node.name] to override
[2019-02-21T16:55:11,063][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [5ZUrCC7] version[6.
6.0], pid[6184], build[default/zip/a9861f4/2019-01-24T11:27:09.439740Z], OS[Wind
ows 7/6.1/x86], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM/1.8.0_181/25.1
81-b13]
[2019-02-21T16:55:11,063][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [5ZUrCC7] JVM argume
nts [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction
=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.
networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.he
adless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastT
hrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty
.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.di
sable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\O846C~1.OAM\AppData\Local\Temp\elastic
search, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=lo
gs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenu
ringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+
UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Xms200m
, -Xmx500m, -Delasticsearch, -Des.path.home=C:\Users\o.o amoo\Downloads\elastics
earch-6.6.0\elasticsearch-6.6.0, -Des.path.conf=C:\Users\o.o amoo\Downloads\elas
ticsearch-6.6.0\elasticsearch-6.6.0\config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -D
es.distribution.type=zip]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [analysis-common]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [ingest-common]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [lang-expression]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [lang-mustache]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,333][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [lang-painless]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [mapper-extras]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [parent-join]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [percolator]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [rank-eval]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [reindex]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [repository-url]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,343][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [transport-netty4]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [tribe]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-ccr]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-core]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-deprecation]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-graph]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-ilm]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,353][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-logstash]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-ml]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-monitoring]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-rollup]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-security]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-sql]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-upgrade]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,363][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] loaded mod
ule [x-pack-watcher]
[2019-02-21T16:55:21,373][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [5ZUrCC7] no plugins
 loaded
[2019-02-21T16:55:40,286][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [5ZUrCC7] parsed [0
] roles from file [C:\Users\o.o amoo\Downloads\elasticsearch-6.6.0\elasticsearch
-6.6.0\config\roles.yml]
[2019-02-21T16:55:45,288][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [5
ZUrCC7] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is n
ot supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can us
e the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in
elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:163
) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:
150) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwar
eCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:1
24) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-c
li-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:116
) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93)
 ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: X-Pack is not supported and
 Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pa
ck features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.ym
l
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPla
tform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:107) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearningFeatureSet.isRunningOnMlPla
tform(MachineLearningFeatureSet.java:98) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.ml.MachineLearning.createComponents(MachineLe
arning.java:395) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$11(Node.java:470) ~[elasticsea
rch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:
267) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.j
ava:1382) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
 ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.ja
va:471) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java
:708) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
 ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499
) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:473) ~[elasticsearch-6.6
.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:265) ~[elasticsearch-6.6
.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[
elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:212) ~[ela
sticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:333) ~[elas
ticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159
) ~[elasticsearch-6.6.0.jar:6.6.0]
        ... 6 more

C:\Users\Prime Jay\Downloads\elasticsearch-6.6.0\elasticsearch-6.6.0\bin>
```

Honestly,I have no Idea what is going on here.

`localhost:9200` cannot connect
Please help.

.........................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Can you try to run elastisearch with x-pack machine learning disabled? Type: `elasticsearch -E  xpack.ml.enabled=false` instead of plain `elasticsearch`.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik OK I'll give it a shot

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Done that.Its taking too long to respond

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik DUDE!!! IT WORKED!!!! POST IT AS UR ANSWER SO I CAN ACCEPT IT!!!THANKS!!!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is described here:

```
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[X-Pack is not supported and Machine Learning is not available for [windows-x86]; you can use the other X-Pack features (unsupported) by setting xpack.ml.enabled: false in elasticsearch.yml]
```

You'll have to set `xpack.ml.enabled` to false.

You can do it either by setting it directly by command line:

`elasticsearch -E xpack.ml.enabled=false`

or you can add a line to `elasticsearch.yml`:

`xpack.ml.enabled: false`

You can usually find `elasticsearch.yml` in `$ES_HOME/config`.